# Java Morse Code Translator can only play two beeps

Tags: java, java-io, audio, beep, audio-player

I'm trying to make a Morse Code Translator that gets a String message and turns it into a series of beeps corresponding to Morse Code. My current issue is that when I run the program, I only get to listen to too beeps.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import  sun.audio.*;    //import the sun.audio package
import  java.io.*; 

public class Morse{
public static void main(String args[]){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
AudioPlayer MGP = AudioPlayer.player;
AudioStream BGM;
AudioStream BGM2;
try
{
  InputStream test = new FileInputStream("beep-1.wav"); //long beep
  InputStream test2 = new FileInputStream("beep-7.wav"); //short beep
  BGM = new AudioStream(test);
  BGM2 = new AudioStream(test2);

  System.out.println("Bienvenido al traductor de código Morse.");
  System.out.println("Por favor escriba el texto que desea traducir.");
  String mensaje = sc.nextLine();
  char l;

  for(int n = 0; n < mensaje.length(); n++){
  //here goes the sounds
  l = mensaje.charAt(n);
  }
```

And for example, I got the following for a and b:

```
if(l == 'a' || l == 'A'){ //a = *-
     AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM2);
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM);
     Thread.sleep(1000);
} else if(l == 'b' || l == 'B'){ //b = -***
      AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM2);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM2);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM2);
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      }
```

Most of the other letters have the same format, therefore, I should expect the following if I input Ab:
short beep-long beep-long beep-short beep-short beep-short beep-short beep

But, I only get short beep-long beep.

Something similar happens with the letter e (which in morse code is only a short beep):

```
else if(l == 'e' || l == 'E'){ //e = *
    AudioPlayer.player.start(BGM2);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

I would expect short beep-short beep if I input Ee, but I only get a single short beep.

Any idea of why this happens?

Comment: I am not that familar with AudioStream or AudioPlayer TBH, but it seems that your stream is already used on the second attempt you try to play the same sound. Either create a new InputStream that loads the bytes from the sound file (not that good) or cache the bytes from the file and create a new AudioStream based on the cached bytes - will perform a bit better. [This link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/sun.audio/AudioPlayerstopInputStreamarg0.htm) might be interesting - it uses a play() method to instantiate a new InputStream per play-action

Comment: I'm quite new to Java and lack of ideas to cache the files. This is a project intended to work only with the AudioStream, for, and if else control groups, so I didn't understand either the function of that link.